# Which is the database table in which Boost stores the cache expiry time of a node and what is the column name?

Tags: 6, database, caching

I was looking for a way to manually set the Boost expiry time of a node and happened to chance upon the boost_cache table. There is an expire column and I am assuming that it contains the timestamp denoting the expiry time of the database. Then I happened to see the timer column and now I am confused as to which column houses the expire timestamp.  Could someone explain?

Site runs on Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on [boost_schema()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!boost!boost.install/function/boost_schema/6), the description of those fields is the following:

- expire: UNIX timestamp for the expiration date of cached page
- timer: Time in milliseconds that the page took to be generated

The expiration time is contained in the "expire" database column.

Comment: Thanks. That does nail the thing. Now I know what the hook_schema stands for.

Comment: You are very welcome. `:)`